# I want to be able to specify a style for a tooltip on some MenuItems, how do I do that?

Tags: wpf

I want to specify a template for the tooltips of some MenuItem controls on my views. I've put the following into a resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}" x:Key="MenuItemToolTip">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
            <HeaderedContentControl>
                <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Background="#2288C6" Foreground="White" Padding="3">Click to report a bug</TextBlock>
                </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
                <HeaderedContentControl.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,5">Please do <Run FontWeight="Bold">not</Run> change the send To email address.</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Also, leave the <Run FontStyle="Italic">BUG: BOTS</Run> in the subject line alone.</TextBlock>
                        <!-- more text blocks, but removed for brevity -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </HeaderedContentControl.Content>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Then in one of the views I've tried using it like so:

```
<MenuItem Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF706C6C" Command="{Binding ViewBugReportingCommand}">
<MenuItem.Style>
    <Style Resources="{StaticResource MenuItemToolTip}" />
</MenuItem.Style>
<MenuItem.Header>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource BugIconData}"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          Fill="#77000000"
          Width="20"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.25,0.25"
          Height="20" />
</MenuItem.Header>
```

At first I tried this, but this was just as bad:

```
<MenuItem Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF706C6C" Command="{Binding ViewBugReportingCommand}" ToolTip="{StaticResource MenuItemToolTip}">
<MenuItem.Header>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource BugIconData}"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          Fill="#77000000"
          Width="20"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.25,0.25"
          Height="20" />
</MenuItem.Header>
```

So, how do I get my style into a resource dictionary so that I can use it on some MenuItems, but not all?

Comment: Create the tooltip and put the style ON the tooltip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first approach is that `Style.Resources` accepts a `ResourceDictionary` but you are setting it to a `Style`

Your second approach does not work because you are applying a `Style` object to the `ToolTip` property. So an implicit `ToolTip` is created which tries to Render your style. But since `Style` is not a `UIElement`, 
what you get is a TextBlock with it's `Text` property set to whatever text is returned from `Style.ToString`, which is the name of the `Style` class by default.

The simplest way here would be to explicitly create a `ToolTip` for each of your `MenuItem`s and set the styles there. For example:

```
<MenuItem Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF706C6C" Command="{Binding ViewBugReportingCommand}">
    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style={StaticResource MenuItemToolTip} Content="Your Tooltip text" />
    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
</MenuItem>
```

Another option would be to add an implicit style to the `Resources` property of the MenuItem so that it will be applied 
to all `ToolTip`s inside the visual tree of the `MenuItem`.

```
<MenuItem ToolTip="Hello">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            .. setters
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

I prefer the former because it's the simplest.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as to what's going on and why what you suggested would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the tooltip style directly by using the tooltip control like this:

```
<MenuItem Background="{x:Null}"
          Foreground="#FF706C6C"
          Command="{Binding ViewBugReportingCommand}">
    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource MenuItemToolTip}" />
    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
    ...
</MenuItem>
```